# Can Graph DBs perform well with unspecified end nodes?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have been experimenting with neo4j for a very specific scenario and I have been unable to get it to perform well - queries take minutes to return. I am wondering if this is a case of the wrong technology for the job?

A simplified version of my scenario is below. I have `Town`s that are linked to each other via routes. Each route has a distance.

[image]

The question I'm trying to ask is: calculate the shortest route from `Town A` to every other town reachable from `Town A`. In this scenario, there are an unspecified number of end nodes. This query takes minutes to return with a small dataset and doesn't return at all for larger data sets with 50,000 nodes.

If I ask the question: calculate the shortest route from `Town A` to `Town E` the response is seemingly instant. In this scenario, both the start and end nodes are known.

My question is, are graph dbs good for the open ended questions (calculate the shortest route from `Town A` to every other town reachable from `Town A`)? If so, is it just my approach to structuring the data that is hampering the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure looks good (maybe you could add an "Intersection" vertex with a "ROAD" edge with a length stored on the ROAD edge, but not sure what data you have available) and YES this is most definitely a good use case for graphs.

I haven't used Neoj4 much, but the problem most likely is the approach you are taking with the algorithm (query) involved.

Neo4j should easily handle what you're looking to accomplish. I would recommend watching some Neo4j videos on the topic and mimic their approach to the shortest path algorithms.

Neo4j(Shortest-Path): https://youtu.be/baEeRfuK1Nk

The graph database I've always used to implement these has always been on TigerGraph, but all graph databases would be able to handle 50,000 nodes quickly.

TigerGraph (Shortest-Path): https://youtu.be/Ra0qORVKsWs

**EDITED** (adding documentation links):

NEO4J

**Single Source Shortest Path algorithm**

Docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/single-source-shortest-path/

TIGERGRAPH

**Single-Source Shortest Path (unweighted)**

Docs: https://docs.tigergraph.com/v/2.6/graph-algorithm-library#single-source-shortest-path-unweighted

Code: https://github.com/tigergraph/gsql-graph-algorithms/blob/master/algorithms/schema-free/shortest_ss_no_wt.gsql

**Single-Source Shortest Path (weighted)**

Docs: https://docs.tigergraph.com/v/2.6/graph-algorithm-library#single-source-shortest-path-weighted

Code: https://github.com/tigergraph/gsql-graph-algorithms/blob/master/algorithms/schema-free/shortest_ss_any_wt.gsql

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the neo4j video which was instructional. It did seem to be focused around the shortest path between two points. I'm looking for the shortest path between one point and all other points. This seems to be a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028942/neo4j-cypher-find-all-paths-exploring-sorted-relationships?rq=1

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is called single source shortest path https://www.techiedelight.com/single-source-shortest-paths-dijkstras-algorithm/. This sort of algorithm should be able to be handled by pretty much any database but the algorithmic complexity (O(e logV)) means that it will take some time to calculate the results, especially in any sort of highly connected dataset

Comment: For anybody else, `Single Shortest Path` solved my problem. In Neo4j you need to install the Graph Data Science Library and make use of this function: `gds.alpha.shortestPath.deltaStepping.stream`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are other graph databases and other graph query languages, here is how to solve the problem using **Objectivity/DB** and its **DO query language**. (See the following question for graph schema and setup: [Link to schema and setup.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124059/weighted-graph-database-recommedations/66289612#66289612) )

```
CREATE WEIGHT CALCULATOR routeDistance {
    minimum:   0,
    default:   0, 
    edges: {
          ()-[r:Road]->(): r.distance
    }
};

Match m = MAX WEIGHT 100.0 routeDistance 
            ((:Town {name == 'TownA'})-[*]->(tEnd:Town)) 
            group by tEnd.name 
            order by Weight(m) asc 
            return tEnd.name, weight(m);
```

The query starts by specifying a MAX WEIGHT that serves to limit the search. Set this value to a value greater than the maximum weight that will be encountered if you want to look at all possible results. Next, we use the user-defined "routeDistance" weight calculator to specify how edge-weights are to be calculated (see the linked question for description of this.) Then we group by the end point (tEnd.name) and order by the weight for each end point.

The results, based on the referenced graph are:

```
{
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownD',
    weight(m):3.00000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownB',
    weight(m):4.00000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownE',
    weight(m):4.00000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownF',
    weight(m):8.00000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownG',
    weight(m):11.0000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownH',
    weight(m):21.0000
  },
  _Projection
  {
    tEnd.name:'TownC',
    weight(m):31.0000
  }
}
```